# VueMq custom breakpoints and imports

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, vuejs2

I import and try and define my breakpoints in my main `app.js`

```
 import VueMq from 'vue-mq';

    Vue.use(VueMq, {
      breakpoints: {
        xsmall: 500,
        small: 768,
        medium: 1024,
        large: 1360,
        xlarge: 1800
      }
    });
```

It's bound to Vue with `Vue.use` so I should be able to us the global `$mq` in any component.

```
 {{ $mq }}
```

However this just returns the default breakpoints (tablet, laptop) and not the my custom ones.

However if I import it all again in the component it works. I get the strings I expect - xsmall, small etc.

```
import VueMq from 'vue-mq';
Vue.use(VueMq, {
  breakpoints: {
    xsmall: 500,
    small: 768,
    medium: 1024,
    large: 1360,
    xlarge: 1800
  }
});
```

How can I get it working globally without having to import in every component?

Comment: Could you set up a jsfiddle or similar?  provide/inject would do this without importing but this looks like it should just work from the library docs.

Answer (score 0):

try install this component to vue by add function install in component's entry file.like:

```
import VueMq from './vue-mq.vue'
const VueMq = {
    install: function(Vue){
        Vue.component('VueMq', VueMq)
    }
}

export default VueMq
```